# Sci-hub and ResearchGate

Tags: copyright, publishers, sci-hub

[Sci-hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub) and [ResearchGate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ResearchGate) both provide (among other things) online access to journals that sit behind publisher paywalls. For example, I have just discovered, not unhappily, most of my own papers on both sites despite the copyright being held by the original publishers and despite none of the publishers apparently having allowed free access to the papers.

Yet, despite their similarities ...

- Sci-hub seems to be regarded by publishers as a rogue site that ought
  to be shut down (consider, for example, multiple news stories about
  [Elsevier's attempts](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature.2017.22196) over the years to recover damages from Sci-hub or to prevent its websites from being [DNS indexed](https://torrentfreak.com/domain-registry-takes-sci-hubs-se-domain-name-offline-230126/) or [publicized](https://www.science.org/content/article/twitter-shuts-down-account-sci-hub-pirated-papers-website))
- ResearchGate is either well-regarded, or at least tolerated .

Have I understood the situation correctly, and if so, what has led to the current state of affairs?

**Added**: To remove doubt, I'm not asking why it might be acceptable to publish a preprint with the permission of the publisher but unacceptable to publish the final paper without the permission of the publisher. I'm interested why comparable behavior on the two sites is apparently treated, and regarded, differently.

Answer (score 4):

Sci-hub allows access to pay-walled articles.   They are like the 'robin hood' of academia.  Hence, they have many fans, especially among institutions who do not have the funds to subscribe to journal databases and proponents of open access.  Further, people who access sci-hub tend to have access to pay-walled articles. I for example use sci-hub to get an easier access to articles; my university's library access sucks.  Hence, publishers do not really care much.  This is because those who can pay are already paying, and those who cannot, they are never a customer.

Researchgate has a bad reputation.  It has questionable practices.  For example, it spammed my co-authors using my name hoping to increase their subscribers.  I also suspect that many subscribers who follow me are fake.

**Additions**:  Elsevier is a profit driven company; search for their annual revenue. ResearchGate allows publishers or copyright holders (or authors) to request their works to be removed from ResearchGate. Further, many publishers, such as IEEE, allow preprints to be posted as long as preprints have a blurb that indicate their copyright owner. Hence, ResearchGate arguably is nicer to publishers and/or do not infringe on publishers' rights. On the other hand, sci-hub is setup to get around a pay-wall, meaning it is a threat to publishers.

Answer (score 3):

One answer to your distilled form of the question (from a comment)

> why is ResearchGate apparently tolerated by publishers whereas Sci-hub is relentlessly pursued, at least by Elsevier?

might be the following. ResearchGate, at least in my experience, do not put full-texts of paywalled articles on their website without consent from at least one of the authors.  So it is the author who is at fault if this is done in violation of their agreements with the journal. It's really not much different to an author putting the published version on their personal website - the publisher doesn't go after the website host if this happens.

Answer (score 2):

**ResearchGate is legal, Sci-Hub is not**

How is that possible when they both "provide access to paywalled papers"? That's when you need to know what exactly is copyrighted and cannot be shared.

[Elsevier sharing policy](https://www.elsevier.com/about/policies/sharing) (which is typical of publishers)

> **Preprint**
> Authors can share their preprint anywhere at any time.
>
> **Accepted Manuscript**
> Authors can share their accepted manuscript:
>
> Immediately
>
> - via their non-commercial personal homepage or blog
> - by updating a preprint in arXiv or RePEc with the accepted manuscript
> - via their research institute or institutional repository for internal institutional uses or as part of an invitation-only research collaboration work-group
> - directly by providing copies to their students or to research collaborators for their personal use
> - for private scholarly sharing as part of an invitation-only work group on commercial sites with which Elsevier has an agreement
>
> After the embargo period
>
> - via non-commercial hosting platforms such as their institutional repository
> - via commercial sites with which Elsevier has an agreement

It should be obvious that ResearchGate generally does not violate these guidelines (and if they do, a DMCA takedown request gets them to remove the offending copyrighted material).

This is in stark contrast with Sci-Hub, which is a pirate website that treats copyright laws with contempt.

**Also**: the methods Sci-Hub uses to get their papers are dubious at best (it's possible some sympathetic researchers donate their institutional credentials to Sci-Hub, but that still almost surely violates their institutional policies) and [outright illegal at worst](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/50490/does-sci-hub-use-malware-and-phishing-to-obtain-researchers-login-credentials). ResearchGate's papers are acquired legally.

The two websites are not comparable.

Comment: Since the answer has been edited, I deleted the discussion about phishing  and **[moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142629/discussion-on-answer-by-allure-sci-hub-and-researchgate) the other comments; please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: The opening statement of this answer is, I think, fundamentally incorrect. Only very few things are "illegal" under the copyright law of most countries, including the US. Instead, owenership of copyright gives rise to what is known as a "chose in action" (see, for example, the Merriam dictionary). Elsevier's pursuit of Sci-Hub relates directly to a chose in action and to the recovery of damages and various other injunctive relief, non of which declares copyright breaches themselves "illegal". Later contempt of court orders *might* be illegal.

Comment: @CrimsonDark sounds like you have a pretty unusual definition of "illegal" - although given that SciHub has already demonstrated contempt of court orders, they are still illegal.